# Java executable .JAR file runs but doesn't open

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, executable-jar

Hey guys I am new to programming and trying to make a java program in eclipse that has a laughing skull gif with a laughing sound. I'm trying to export it as a runnable .JAR file and it starts running but it never fully opens.

I have tried changing paths in windows, java is updated, i have run jarfix, i don't have malware on my computer, i have uninstalled and reinstalled java and eclipse. I don't know how to fix it and am in need of some help.

*here is my code*

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.io.File;
    
    public class Laughingskull extends JFrame
    {                   
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        /**
         * 
         */         
        public ImageIcon skull;
        public JLabel label;
        

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {                                               
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            Laughingskull frame = new Laughingskull();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
            File Laugh = new File("evillaugh.WAV");
            PlaySound(Laugh);       
        }


        
        //customPanel   
    public Laughingskull() {        
        skull = new ImageIcon("fireskull.gif");
        label = new JLabel(skull);
        add(label); 
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));          
        }       


    
    static void PlaySound(File Sound) {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
            clip.start();       
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
            System.exit(0);
        }catch(Exception e) {                   
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hello you should maybe try to run the jar from a command line and add the stacktrace in the question

Comment: hey Ruokki i have tried running from the command line but the jar always comes back "error unable to access jarfile" and what do you mean by add stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace are the error log printed by the throws of exception. But in your case you don't have one because the jar is not launch. What is the command you use for launching the jar ?

Comment: Never write an empty `catch` block.  Always, at the very least, print or log the full stack trace.  In your case, you can do that with `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: @Ruokki in the cmd line i use "java -jar laughingskull.jar" because thats what i named it on export.

Comment: thank you @VGR i'll try that and see if it helps.